# Google sheets - sum columns with multiple criteria

Tags: arrays, formula

I've searched various posts and need the straightforward answer to summing a column with various criteria from other columns.

Hypothetically, I'm working to sum various numbers/amounts in Column A with criteria in Column B and C and maybe D. Column B would be a date. Column C would be a text cell, i.e. "C1". Column D could be another text field.

I've attempted to work with SUMIFS but am likely confused. My gut tells me this might be an Arrayformula, but I get a bit crossed up. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: you can use also sumproduct, share a minimal reproducible example!

Comment: Here's an example. Col A is the revenue. Col B is Stage and is the first criteria. Col C is the date with date format. Col D is the month number, which is the second criteria. I'd like to get the total revenue per Close Month where the Stage is C1 only. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1agrg_PLpfHd99hc0dSAMEdGo9sTCD7RWBt9DwXMaSFo/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to make a pivot table without any calculation.

Group dates by year-month

[image]